# Select only rows which relation Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a problem with selecting only rows with relations. I've tried many different solutions. I have 2 tables `Movies` and `Movie_links`. I want to get only movies which have links.

Models:

Movie.php

```
public function links()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Movie_link', 'movie', 'id');
}
```

Movie_link.php

```
public function movie()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Movie', 'movie','id')->first();
}
```

Controller:

I use this code to get all movies which have links and this code works but i want something more efficient:

```
Movie::latest()
    ->select('id', 'title', 'poster', 'rating')
    ->whereIn('id', Movie_link::select('movie')->distinct()->pluck('movie'))
    ->wherenotnull('poster')
    ->limit(14)
    ->get()
```

But I want more performance so I want to use this code:

```
Movie::has('links')
    ->select('id', 'title', 'poster', 'rating')
    ->withCount('links')
    ->orderByDesc('id')
    ->limit(14)
    ->get()
```

But with this code request takes 15 seconds! If I change `DESC` to `ASC` it is good.

Comment: Do you need the count? Why not just do: `$movies= Movie::has('links')->orderByDesc('id')->limit(14)->get();`

Comment: Did you add indexes to your database?

Comment: `wherenotnull` should be `whereNotNull`; case sometimes doesn't matter, but for consistency and readability consider changing it.

Comment: Of course i have `id` in Movies and `movie` in movie_links. I want to get only Movies with links. U can look at the first code to get that what i want.

Comment: I usually switch `get()` to `toSql()` and dd() result. Then use mysql client to run raw query to investigate performance or other mysql query issues. (mysql EXPLAIN to check used indexes)

Comment: But i will mess up all if i will change to query. I just want make this better for speed and for better look.

Comment: Vaidas is suggesting to change to `->toSql()` so you can view the raw query, use it in a client like MySQLWorkbench to see if there are any deficiencies (using `EXPLAIN()`), then see if you can fix anything, like indicies, etc. They aren't saying to change it to a raw query; at least not permanently. It's good advice; you should consider trying that debugging approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a join:

```
Movie::query()->from('Movies as M')
              ->join('Movie_links as L', 'M.id', '=', 'L.movie')
              ->select('M.id', 'M.title', 'M.rating', 'M.poster', DB::raw('COUNT(L.id) as C'))
              ->groupBy('M.id')
              ->having('C', '>', 0)
              ->orderByDesc('M.id')
              ->limit(14)
              ->get();
```

Comment: Work well! This is more efficient.